# "The method addActionListener(ActionListener) in the type AbstractButton is not applicable for the arguments"

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, actionlistener

I am a beginner programmer and I am running into a problem with an action listener and my GUI. Here is my code:

MAIN CLASS--

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class prog extends JFrame {

//add instance variable to hold lockd
prog app = new prog();

//create buttons
JPanel row1 = new JPanel();
JButton oneLeft = new JButton("oneLeft");
JButton oneRight = new JButton("oneRight");

JPanel row2 = new JPanel();
JButton twoLeft = new JButton("twoLeft");
JButton twoRight = new JButton("twoRight");

JPanel row3 = new JPanel();
JButton threeLeft = new JButton("threeLeft");
JButton threeRight = new JButton("threeRight");


public prog() {
    super("Prog");
    setLookAndFeel();
    setSize(400, 800);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(3, 2);
    setLayout(layout);

    //add Listeners
    oneLeft.addActionListener(app);
    oneRight.addActionListener(app);
    twoLeft.addActionListener(app);
    twoRight.addActionListener(app);
    threeLeft.addActionListener(app);
    threeRight.addActionListener(app);



    setVisible(true);
}

private void setLookAndFeel() {
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.plaf.");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //ignore error
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    prog progApp = new prog();
}
}
```

I am getting an error in this class with the action listeners: The method addActionListener(ActionListener) in the type AbstractButton is not applicable for the arguments (prog).

Full errors:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The method addActionListener(ActionListener) in the type AbstractButton is not applicable for the arguments (prog)  prog.java   /Experiment/src line 33 Java Problem
The method addActionListener(ActionListener) in the type AbstractButton is not applicable for the arguments (prog)  prog.java   /Experiment/src line 35 Java Problem
The method addActionListener(ActionListener) in the type AbstractButton is not applicable for the arguments (prog)  prog.java   /Experiment/src line 34 Java Problem
The method addActionListener(ActionListener) in the type AbstractButton is not applicable for the arguments (prog)  prog.java   /Experiment/src line 37 Java Problem
The method addActionListener(ActionListener) in the type AbstractButton is not applicable for the arguments (prog)  prog.java   /Experiment/src line 36 Java Problem
The method addActionListener(ActionListener) in the type AbstractButton is not applicable for the arguments (prog)  prog.java   /Experiment/src line 38 Java Problem
```

and here is my listener class:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class progEvent implements ActionListener {

prog GUI;
String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separater");


public progEvent(prog in) {
    GUI = in;
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    String command = event.getActionCommand();
    try {
        File numClicks = new File("numClicks.properties");
        FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(numClicks);

        if (command.equals("oneLeft")) {
            write(outStream, "oneLeft has been clicked.");  
        }
        if (command.equals("oneRight")) {
            write(outStream, "oneRight has been clicked.");
        }
        if (command.equals("twoLeft")) {
            write(outStream, "twoLeft has been clicked.");
        }
        if (command.equals("twoRight")) {
            write(outStream, "twoRight has been clicked.");
        }
        if (command.equals("threeLeft")) {
            write(outStream, "threeLeft has been clicked.");
        }
        if (command.equals("threeRight")) {
            write(outStream, "threeRight has been clicked.");
        }
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("The file could not be written to.");
    }
}

void write(FileOutputStream stream, String output) throws IOException {
    output = output + newLine;
    byte[] data = output.getBytes();
    stream.write(data, 0, data.length);
}
}
```

I can't get my GUI to show either. I'm using a book to learn it, and using a class as a kind of template for this experiment. But I'm completely stuck. Thanks!

Comment: It's standard practice in Java to capitalize class names; using `Prog` and `ProgEvent` will help other people who are trying to read your code.  Also, please copy the whole error message, including the line/character numbers.

Comment: I know, I just had to change some stuff around and posted it. The code is a little sloppy I know, but I'm trying to focus on getting it running. Thanks though. Updated with errors.

Comment: `app` is is of the type `prog` which is an instance of `JFrame` which is NOT an instance of `ActionListener`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to add an instance of your `prog` class as the `ActionListener`, but your `ActionListener` is `progEvent` instead. You need to add a `progEvent listener = new progEvent();` and then `addActionListener(progEvent)`.

(Also, you misspelled "separator" in your system property; you won't retrieve what you're looking for.)

Comment: Where would I add the progEvent listener = new progEvent(); ? Would it be in the main class where the add actionlistener statements are?

Comment: Yes. Since you're wanting to use the same instance of the listener to handle all of the button clicks (which isn't the usual practice), you need to make a variable to hold it right above where you attach it. If you need to hold on to it for some reason to have it available later, you'd put the variable as a field (outside any method, usually at the top of the class).

Comment: When I try to add that line, I get progEvent() is undefined. But the first part of the statement "progEvent listeneter =" is fine, and recognizes fine. But "new progEvent();" gives me that error.

Comment: Look at the constructor for your `progEvent` class. (And please do change the capitalization... it's only a convention, but it's so strong it's confusing to read your code.)

Comment: Not necessarily a variable, but an object. In your case, you probably want to say `new progEvent(this);`.

Comment: Thanks!! You got it working! Haha. I found out why the GUI wouldn't show, I didn't have the buttons added. My new question is, how come only ONE action listener works? It seems to only work for the first button clicked. But I want it to record every button clicked. Do I need to make separate action listeners for each button?

Answer (score 0):

Your class should implement ActionListener. so your prog definition should be "prog extends JFrame implements ActionListener". Then implement your actionperformed .
for example

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        if ("connect".equalsIgnoreCase(arg0.getActionCommand())) {
            connect();
        }

    }
```